# Making multiple fields NULL using Python in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a repetitive task here at work. It requires that I make multiple fields NULL as I update the geodatabase. Is there a script I can write that I can input the fields and the feature class. Then make all those fields NULL. This script must not make everything NULL in the feature class, only the fields designated.
    import arcpy

```
fc = "N:\Updates\CarsonCityNV\CarsonCityNV.gdb\J_POC_S_Studies_Ln"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("C1_GAGE", "C2_DISCH", "C3_MODEL", "C4_FCSTR", "C5_CHANN", "C6_HSTR, "C7_SCOUR", "S1_REGEQ", "S2_REPLO",     "S3_IMPAR", "S4_HSTR", "S5_CHIMP", "S6_TOPO", "S7_VEGLU", "S9_HWMS", "S10_REGEQ", "CE_TOTAL", "SE_TOTAL", "A1_TOPO", "A2_HYDRO", "A3_IMPAR", "A4_TECH", "A5_FOAPASS")) as cursor:
 for row in cursor:
    row[0] = None
    row[1] = None
    row[2] = None
    row[3] = None
    row[4] = None
    row[5] = None
    row[6] = None
    row[7] = None
    row[8] = None
    row[9] = None
    row[10] = None
    row[11] = None
    row[12] = None
    row[13] = None
    row[14] = None
    row[15] = None
    row[16] = None
    row[17] = None
    row[18] = None
    row[19] = None
    row[20] = None
    row[21] = None
    row[22] = None
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I'm getting a parsing error on line 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the path of `fc` to your feature class, and change `YourField` to the field name.

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:\\Temp\\Data.gdb\\FeatureClass"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("YourField")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = None
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

To do multiple fields, just add another field to the tuple and set the row equal to `None`:

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:\\Temp\\Data.gdb\\FeatureClass"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("YourField", "YourField2")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = None
        row[1] = None
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: You are awesome man, just saved me loads of time. I will try it out. Can I also use this to populate fields with something other than null?

Comment: @ChristopherHarrod yeah, instead of setting the `row` equal to `None`, just set it to whatever value you want that fits the field type. If it's a text field, you need to enclose the text in quotes, such as `row[0] = "This is my text"`

Comment: If I have a thousand rows, will I have to declare each one? i.e. row [0] row [1] row [2]... and so on.

Comment: No, `row[0]` is actually identifying a field in the tuple. In the example above, `row[0]` is `"YourField"`, and `row[1]` is `"YourField2"`. So, it is populating `None` for every row in each field that you designate - this might explain it better: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158958/using-square-brackets-in-arcpy-update-cursor/158963#158963

Comment: Ok, great, I will give it a go.

Comment: @ChristopherHarrod  Why field default value is not an option?

Comment: Getting parsor error on line 5

Comment: @ian I'm still getting an error. I ran it on one field and it worked fine. I think it has to do with the multiple fields i entered.

Comment: @ian I have it working now. I had to run it one field, then two fields, then I finally found the error with one of the fields. Not sure what it was but I rewrote the field name and the row[] and it worked. Thanks for your help.